# Is there an open source NSView based UINavigationController like component?

Tags: cocoa, appkit

I am looking for a navigation controller for my Mac app.  I can build one but just making sure there are no `UINavigationController` like open source examples I could use to create a push-pop style `NSViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at the [Chameleon project](http://chameleonproject.org/)? It's an implementation of UIKit, and I suspect it doesn't actually work with the `NSView` but requires writing UIKit code. It, however, does sound like it might be an even better solution for your needs.